# JPA: two objects seems to be the same after saving one of them

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to call a method that generates an `audit` comparing two `QdCF`objects:

```java
public Auditoria mapToModificacio(QdCF current, @QdCF incoming);
```

From my service, I first obtain current database stored `current`:

```java
QdCF current = this.qdcfRepository.getReferenceById(qdcfPresenter.getId());
```

After that, I save `incoming` object:

```java
QdCF savedQdcf = this.qdcfRepository.save(incoming);
```

After that, I call my `audit` generator:

```java
Auditoria audit = this.auditoriaMapper.mapToModificacio(savedQdcf, current);
```

However, after having saved incoming object, it seems that `current` and `savedQdcf` are reference the same object. Hence, there aren't any modifcation between both ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: if `incoming`and `current` have the same id (`@id` of the entity), then it is hibernate's job to insure they are represented by the same java object if they are both attached to the same hibernate session. Therefore, after having saved incoming, `saveQdcf` and `current` reference the same object.

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Is there any way to keep both independent?

Comment: I think that you should compare them before saving.

Comment: What are you doing with the Audit? You can use lifecycle events from hibernate to get the pre/post changes - see PostUpdateEvent in https://medium.com/swlh/harnessing-hibernate-events-for-data-change-detection-52981f4badf0 . Other providers (EclipseLink in particular) can give you the changeset it calculated and used for the transaction, allowing changes to be coordinated to remote caches and in custom auditing - pretty sure Hibernate will have something similar, I'm just less familiar with it. Such functions would save you  from redoing the same calculations.